# unable to send push notification to ios using fcm token firebase

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried sending notification using firebase notification console it worked fine but with code it throws error
{"multicast_id":469219618584251399,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
my code:-

```
<?php
define('API_ACCESS_KEY','Server key');

'to'        => $token, //single token
'notification' => $notification,
'data' => $extraNotificationData
];
$headers = [
'Authorization: key=API_ACCESS_KEY',
'Content-Type: application/json'
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. The token generated from the iOS side was wrong.

Following is the code that was using earlier:-

```
UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```

Now I am using the following code at my side:-

```
 Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
```